# AWS Application Load Balancer sends request to unhealthy target groups / instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

In my AWS VPC I have an application load balancer and two target groups. Each target group has only 1 instances in different az with health check setup.

Now when one of my instance in a target group goes down AWS correctly marks its as unhealthy. But my application load balancer still keeps sending requests to it, causing my application to work intermittently.

[image]

*But in the documentation it's clearly mentioned that unhealthy instances are ignored by the load balancer.*

I checked all the LB and TG configuration none suggest that they shouldn't be ignored.

> It monitors the health of its registered targets, and routes traffic
> only to the healthy targets.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an **exception** from this rule. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html):

> If a target group contains **only unhealthy registered** targets, the load balancer nodes route requests across its unhealthy targets.

So basically, if all targets are unhealhty, ALB will ignore this fact and attempt to route requests to the targets anyway.

Comment: I thought so too, forgot to mention that I tried and kept both instances in the same target group. So basically one healthy and one unhealthy and still both instances were been requested. 

Comment: @botchedDevil Your screenshot shows only one target, so I'm not sure which two instances are you referring to?

Comment: @botchedDevil There is also de-registration time. You may had to wait longer?

Comment: Yes As I said I forgot to mention that case when I had put two instances in the same Target Group. I was still getting the issue

Comment: @botchedDevil Please double check. There must be something more that maybe you missed or forgot to mention.

Comment: No that's it, let me know if you need to know anything specific!